# Chromecast sending Bitmap to receiver

Tags: javascript, android, google-cast

Using the Chromecast dongle we are trying to show a Bitmap originating from android that changes often onto the receiver. The way we are currently doing it is converting the image to Base64 and then submitting that as the URL. This works but is very slow and seems inefficient. What would be the best way to show a local Bitmap onto the receiver?

Relevant Java code:

```
Bitmap bitmap1 = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length, options);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
bitmap1.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, baos);
String image = "data:image/jpeg;base64,"+Base64.encodeToString(baos.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);
mMessageStream.loadMedia(image, mMetaData, true);
```

receiver.html:

```
<html>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/cast/js/receiver/1.0/cast_receiver.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    var receiver = new cast.receiver.Receiver(
        'ACTUAL_APP_ID_HERE', [cast.receiver.RemoteMedia.NAMESPACE],
        "",
        3);
    var remoteMedia = new cast.receiver.RemoteMedia();
    remoteMedia.addChannelFactory(
        receiver.createChannelFactory(cast.receiver.RemoteMedia.NAMESPACE));

    receiver.start();

    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
      var elem = document.getElementById('vid');
      remoteMedia.setMediaElement(elem);
    });
</script>

<body>
<img id="vid" style="position:absolute;top:0;left:0;height:100%;width:100%" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably not the best method, but I have my app start a local web server, and send the correct link to the receiver. On an http request, the server then streams the file from the disk. I haven't tested to see how fast/often it can be changed.

Comment: It would be interesting to benchmark if this makes any difference (sending the Bitmap over the WebSockets connection vs letting the Receiver load it over HTTP). Starting a HTTP server seems like it would just add some indirection to the flow, I can't imagine why that would be faster than just streaming it over WebSockets, but then again I don't know a lot about the inner workings of the protocol.

Comment: I had the same problem with C#.Trouble sending a local image to Chromecast from the console app.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Base64OutputStream](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64OutputStream.html) with other streams, right now you are just loading whole image into memory which is very bad and will give you out of memory error sooner or later.

Comment: Are you saying I would run out of memory on the Android device or the Chromecast dongle? I do need the image in Bitmap form on the Android device to put into an ImageView later on.